# How can I securely carry and switch between two cameras for sports photography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-straps

I've been doing some sport photography and love blurry panning shots - I recently acquired a second body which is brilliant for cutting down lens changes but I now find that my panning ability is compromised by the inertia of my second camera; either that or I'm distracted by it threatening to fall off my shoulder or bash into a fence post. It's not too bad if I slip it over my head and shoulder but then I get into a tangle with the straps, particularly if I'm wearing a hood; it's all very awkward.

What solutions are there for carrying two cameras whilst still having free movement, being able to switch between them easily and not worrying about dropping them or bashing them into something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I use a [Black Rapid Double Breathe](http://www.blackrapid.com/Double-Breathe) and usually carry two gripped full frame bodies, two pro lenses (usually 24-70 + 70-200 (occasionly with a 2x)) along with flashes. No problem. It also comes apart into two seperate single harnesses if you only have one body with you (you can use a double harness with one camera... but it sits lop sided and you look like a twit).

That's my personal preference.

Whatever you spend your money on I recommend doing some research. I switched from two shoulder straps to a harness after spending 12 hours on my feet at a music festival and by the end was in pain. I've never looked back since making the switch. But these are the points I would consider. For any system.

1. **Weight distribution/padding**. Two camera bodies get heavy, not neccessarily straight away but after time, and you do want to get one padded to stop digging int your shoulders.
2. **Asjustability**. Can you adjust the strap to make it comfortable to use/carry.
3. **Build Quality**. eBay (for example) is filled with off market straps very similar, usually from China. Due to unbranding finding a manufacturer can be hard. You need one which isn't going to fail, either leaving you with cameras and no way to carry them, or worse.. they crash on the ground and you have an insurance claim to make. Things to be mindful of are any points of failure. Clips and moving parts. The material the straps are made from too. Don't forget a lot of weight/money is going to be relying on this strap. Don't scrimp and get a cheaper option which looks the same. **Hint: If it has a manufacturer guarantee (the longer the better) then it's a good sign. The company has faith in their product., as they wouldn't offer it, if everyone ended up claiming on them**
4. **Can you carry an additional bag and be comfortable.** Seriously. You may not be transporting your gear on the straps, and may have extra gear with you. Can you keep use of your strap whilst still having access to the bags? (I can use either a backpack and/or a belt mounted lens pouch with mine).
5. **Does it have guards.** I didn't know about this but on mine I have plastic adjustable guards I cna use to prevent the distance the camera can freely move on the straps by its self. These little things are incredibly useful.
6. **Reviews**. Look on photography blogs etc, see if the product has been reviewed and especially stress tested, in order to get an independent opinion on it.

Answer (score 2):

I use an [Op/Tech Double Sling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004N622H6).

It's as comfortable as any other strap I've ever used, and more comfortable than most. The modular OP/TECH system makes it easy to swap a camera from the harness to a single strap in mere seconds. It also allows the camera to be easily and quickly disconnected from the harness and stored in a case or backpack with only the uniloops still attached to the camera.

I typically have a gripped 5D Mark III with an EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS on the right side and a gripped 7D Mark II with an EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II on the left. Sometimes I'll have a 50mm prime on the 5D Mark III and a 135mm prime on the 7D Mark II or the 135mm will be on the 5DIII and the 50mm will be on a 5D Mark II. I'm a large guy at 6'0" and a little over 300 pounds. It works fine for me.

I have the harness straps cinched up closer to my shoulders than what is shown in the product photos and use [OP/TECH Extensions (Regular)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004N623UW) with the [OP/TECH Uni-Loop - System Connectors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0010HA6A6) included with the harness on the right side. I have the front connector attached to the right camera lug (near the shutter button) and the rear connector attached to the strap lug (NOT the tripod receiver) on the base of the grip. The camera hangs just as shown in the photo except the "X" between the harness strap and the two connectors to the camera is higher up on my torso. I can even attach a full size speedlight (580EX II or YN685) to the camera's hot shoe and it still works well.

On the left side I have the front connector that slides on the harness attached to the strap lug next to the mode dial (on the top left of the camera) using an [OP/TECH Uni-Loop XL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I2PE7AE). I also use an [OP/TECH USA Extension (X-Long)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007NRCUXI) attached to the rear sliding connector as a non-load bearing 'safety strap' attached to the strap lug (NOT the tripod receiver) via an XL uniloop on the bottom of the grip. If for some reason the single load bearing connection on that side of the harness were to fail the 'safety strap' would catch the camera and lens without letting it fall to the ground.

To date I have never had an OP/TECH connector fail. I have had a couple of occasions where I failed to fully click in a quick disconnect and having a redundant connector on both sides prevented a dropped camera and lens!

I sometimes use the harness with a single camera attached on the right side. To keep the harness centered with no weight on the left side I cinch the X-Long extension attached to the rear sliding connector on the left side all the way up, loop it under my belt, and click it back to the front sliding connector.

I also sometimes use the Canon CPS logoed version (provided by the Canon Professional Services program when first joining at the Gold or Platinum level) of the [OP/TECH Utility Strap - 3/8-Inch (Black)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MVZ2IM) as a more traditional neck/shoulder strap. I use the pad from the Utility Strap connected to the left side of the camera via an X-Long extension cinched all the way up (the one I had left from the pair I bought to use one as a safety strap when carrying a camera on the left side of the harness) and a uniloop already attached to the left camera lug. I use the regular extension strap, let out enough to match the length of the X-Long extension on the left side, already attached to the right camera lug via a regular uniloop to connect to the right side of the Utility Strap pad.

It's actually a lot simpler to do than it is to explain here. You just need to pay attention to the male/female ends on the uniloops and extensions. In general the male ends are on the left end of each piece and always point from right to left and click into the female ends on the right end of the next piece. Once the uniloops are attached to each camera with the correct gender on each side I can swap cameras and straps almost effortlessly in just a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Blackrapid](http://www.blackrapid.com/) strap. It can be worn crossbody with a camera on either side but doesn't restrict motion nearly as much as a conventional camera strap. They have several models to choose from...

Answer (score 0):

B&H has [a buyer's guide for dual-camera carrying systems](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/buying-guide/savvy-shooter%E2%80%99s-guide-dual-camera-carrying-systems). :)  Many companies make dual harness/slings/straps for carrying two cameras at the same time.

Both of my cameras are mirrorless, so I find I don't need a heavy-duty solution. I typically wear my cameras on neoprene neck straps, cross-body, so if I'm shooting both of them at the same time, I simply keep one on the right hip, and one on the left, with both straps cross-body. Both cameras are light enough that typically the straps don't trap one another. With prosumer dSLR gear or supertele lenses, it would be a very different story.